# filter a string from sorted list in python

Tags: python, amazon-rds

The code loops through the AWS RDS DB snapshots list and deleted the old snapshot.

```
for db in snapshots_per_db:
    if len(snapshots_per_db[db]): 
        sorted_list = sorted(snapshots_per_db[db].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        print(sorted_list)
        to_remove = [i[0] for i in sorted_list[1:]]

#for snapshot in to_remove:
#    if snapshot['SnapshotCreateTime'] < retentionDate:
#        print("Removing " + snapshot)
#        remote_client.delete_db_snapshot(DBSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot)
```

`print(sorted_list)`   gives:

```
[('db-nightly-split-2020-10-13', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 13, 16, 21, 36, 41000, tzinfo=tzlocal()))]
```

`print(snapshots_per_db[db])`
gives:

```
{'db-nightly-split-2020-10-13': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 13, 16, 21, 36, 41000, tzinfo=tzlocal())}
```

but `to_remove = [i[0] for i in sorted_list[1:]]` is returning an empty array `[]`.

am i doing it wrong? I would need `db-nightly-split-2020-10-13` and other inside `to_remove`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sorted_list` only has 1 item: a tuple of 3 elements.  So `sorted_list[1:]` is everything *after* that one element.

It sounds like you want `to_remove = [i[0] for i in sorted_list]`, but I'm not very confident of that.

Comment: got it. ‍♂️Thank you! :)